# Internet Explorer won't open credentialed links

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, hyperlink, anchor

**Disclaimer: I realize this isn't really secure - it isn't meant to be a security measure.**

So I have several links pointing to sites that have been "Basic Auth" locked down in IIS6.  I have formatted the href in the anchor tags to use the following syntax: http://user:password@dev1.mysite.com

This works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but does not work in Internet Explorer.  IE will not even attempt to go to the destination.  If the url is copy and pasted into the address bar, IE returns what looks like a dns error, which I suppose is a clue to why the links themselves do not work.  Does IE honor a different syntax for this kind of stuff or am I just out of luck with getting something like this to work with IE?

Thanks!

Comment: have to agree with @Joe here, this is nothing you can do other than force people to do the registry entry which would only work for internal users - assuming your talking about a company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489 states this is by design as a security measure.  There is a registry workaround that a user can apply, but there's nothing you can do from the webserver side that will override this.

Comment: I was afraid of that...  thanks for pointing me to the documentation.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this change was in response to a security problem that was rife at the time.

Comment: To be honest it looks like a knee-jerk reaction: "Web site that displays the URL to a legitimate Web site in the Status bar, Address bar, and Title bar of all versions of Internet Explorer."  Why not only show what comes after the @ like every other browser... would solve this problem.  In any case, it looks like bad user experience for my IE users all around.  :\